# utliity/package for monitoring the node

Tags: ros, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am looking a package for monitoring the running node health status.Apart from this i should be able to start/stop/kill  all (particular node) Could you please help
in this regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257036/utliity/package-for--monitoring-the-node/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to use [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt). Just type `rqt` in the terminal to access it. Select "plugins" from the menu bar to see all the tools available.

There are lots of plugins available for it which are also listed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins). I think the [process monitor](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins#Group:_Introspection) plugin under the introspection menu would be useful to you, but there are many others that are helpful as well.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-03-15**:
I came across one of the package listed in github rosspawn (https://github.com/timn/rosspawn). can anybody suggest about this based on their experience.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-03-16**:
That's from 2010, it probably won't work with current ROS.

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-03-16**:
Thanks i will check.